# Convexity of linear least squares problem when rank-deficient matrix

Tags: optimization, least-squares, linear-model, convex

A linear least squares problem is always convex as explained mathematically here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483339/proof-of-convexity-of-linear-least-squares. However, a linear LS can yield infinite solutions if the matrix A (in the general LS problem $min||Ax-b||^2$) is rank-deficient. Also, from theory of convex optimization, the solution can be infinitely-many when the problem is not strictly convex, otherwise if the problem is strictly convex then a unique optimal solution exists. Correlating both, it appears that when A is rank-deficient, the LS problem becomes NON-strictly-convex. How can we reason this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your problem is, but if you're having practical problems fitting a linear model, you should remove columns from your design matrix until it has full rank.

Indeed if $A$ is rank-deficient, then you no longer have a strictly convex optimization problem, but it is still convex. Any local optimum of a convex optimization problem will yield a globally optimal solution, the catch is that there may be multiple optimal solutions (as you already pointed out)

Comment: Thanks. I agree, probably my understanding lacks a basic understanding that when A is rank-deficient, how does the problem become weakly convex necessarily (i.e. the graph would have a flat optimal region)? I am not into math background, so wanted to get a justification for the same, even if it might be straighforward!

Comment: @Maaz Without trying to be too mathy, assume $A$ is rank deficient. Then you get hyperplanes (think flat surfaces) of solutions to $Ax=0$. So if you have any optimal solution, to the OLS then you can think of superimposing one of these hyperplanes over it to get infinitely many optimal solutions. These optimal solutions therefore lie in hyperplanes (which is possibly what you mean by 'flat optimal region'?)

Comment: A bit difficult to comprehend if OLS problem essentially superimposes hyperplanes Ax, though I get the overall picture of when unqiue / infinite solutions may occur. By "flat optimal region", I meant that the convex problem when plotted in the hyperspace of parameters would have a minima hyperplane rather than a unique minima point (in case when we sole OLS with a rank-deficient A)! Thanks though